# Why not show firebase events on console in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-analytics

In my application, I want to show some events in Firebase console.
I want when the user clicks on some buttons, there should be events shown in firebase console.

```
introPage_welcome.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("Login", "IntroLogin");
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("AndroidEvents", bundle);
});
```

But I can't see this event in firebase console!
Where can I see this event in firebase console?
Is my above code correct and how can I use events in the Firebase console?

Comment: The shared code has nothing to do with Firebase. Please add the correct code.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase events logged takes around a day to be reflected on firebase dashboard, check the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?authuser=1&platform=android#view_events_in_the_dashboard), mean while you can debug event and check in realtime for debug device for the events you are logging check the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview?authuser=1)